# Vim inside Blender to work with BPY?

Tags: python, vim, blender

I am trying to write the Python BPY -code inside Blender and noticed some editor -mode ([source](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Blender_3D%3a_Noob_to_Pro/Advanced_Tutorials/Python_Scripting/Export_scripts)) and, instead of reinventing the wheel, I want to use my Vim -syntax-highlighting-etc inside Blender -text-editor. So how can I use Vim inside Blender?

> You can write scripts either in an external text editor, or in
>   Blender's built in text editor. Move to a panel you wish to change to
>   be the text editor, **click the editor select button and choose "text
>   editor" (shortcut) SHIFT+F11. Click the + New button at the bottom.**
>   If you want, you can enable line numbers and syntax coloring with the
>   buttons at the bottom. Create a new script with File → New, paste the
>   code below into it, and save it. Or alternatively, paste the code
>   below into a file, and open that file with File → Open in Blender. As
>   name choose something with the extension .py, for example
>   wikibooks.py. Put it into Blender's user scripts path.

Comment: Perhaps interesting to other newbies [here](http://avp.stackexchange.com/questions/4145/how-to-create-a-rolling-ball-with-python-in-blender) and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10972637/how-can-i-access-bpy-in-standard-python-console-bpy-is-the-blender-python-thin), threads with which I am working.

Answer (score 0):

From the source you provided it looks to me that it doesn't matter what text editor you use as long as you save the python scripts to the file locations provided in that documentation (e.g. ~/.blender/scripts and other OS paths). Not very familiar with blender since I'm answering via the vim tag. Looks like there's potentially a plugin to use an external editor: http://www.blendernation.com/2011/08/02/edit-blender-text-files-using-external-text-editor-plug-in/. Also if you're on Mac then look into QuickCursor: http://www.hogbaysoftware.com/products/quickcursor/.

Comment: Any idea why the plugin is removed? I mean the plugin by Sinan -- I cannot understand why you cannot use some simple text-editor such as vi inside Blender. Trying to program inside text-files and then just source things.